# Como iniciar o servidor NodeJs sem usar editor de texto ou terminal?

Tags: node.js, aplicação-web, lado-do-servidor, lado-do-cliente

Fiz um aplicativo em Node Js, mas preciso de um jeito mais simples para iniciar o meu script para que o cliente não tenha dificulades para inicial o servidor.

Existe alguma solução para para inicial o servidor nodejs sem ser através do terminal ou editor de texto ?

Answer (score 0):

Pode usar o [pkg](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pkg) pra criar um executável pra uma aplicação node.js.

Pode instalar ele usando:

```
npm install -g pkg
```

E pra criar o executável:

```
pkg nomedoarquivo.js
```